# Time Complexity of this Algorithm: is it O(n^2) or O(n)

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am trying to solve "Reverse Words in a String III" of Leetcode. I come up with a solution but I think that my time complexity is O(n^2). My code is able to pass all the test cases. My code is as follows:

```
class Solution {
    public String reverseWords(String s) {
        if(s.isEmpty())
            return "";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();        
        String[] str = s.split("\\s+");
        for(String s1:str){
            char[] c1  = reverseChar(s1);
            result.append(c1).append(" ");
            }
        return result.toString().trim();
    }

    public char[] reverseChar(String s){
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        int j = c.length-1;

        while(i<j){
                char temp = c[i];
                c[i] = c[j];
                c[j] = temp;
                j--;
                i++;
            }
        return c;
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to say it's O(n*m) complexity, where n is number of words and m is the length of the strings.

Comment: What do you think would be the complexity if you did not split it into words? (i.e. reversed the whole string) What do you think is the complexity of splitting it into words? Which is highest?

Comment: You can reduce execution time by using `StringBuilder#reverse` rather than writing a `char[] reverseChar(String s)` method.

Comment: It's just O(n) because you are only iterating through each character once

Comment: @Luggi Mendoza, Why do you think that StringBuilder#reverse will reduce time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

O(n) ... and actually slightly less when the String length is short due to start up / tear down costs of the JVM.

If you're interested in knowing precisely, I recommend researching the Java Micro-benchmarking Harness (JMH) (re: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html).

I do not recommend the following poor-man's benchmark; however, it answers the question all the same.

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        char[] chars = new char[100_000]; // change this value to other benchmarks
                for (char c : chars) {
            c = (char) (r.nextInt(90) + 32);
        }

        Solution s = new Solution();
        long x1  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        s.reverseWords(Arrays.toString(chars));
        long x2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("duration = " + (x2 - x1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the complexity is O(n/2). The code can be abstract as

```
for(int i =0 ,i< str.length, i++){
    for(int j = 0,j < str[i].length/2, j++)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Say str is `['abc','abc','abc','abc']`,the complexity is `4*(3/2) = (4*3)/2`.And `4*3 == n`,So it is O(n/2)